# apache drill 1.19 and oracle 9i, ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested

Tags: oracle, apache-drill

I am building application based on apache drill.

During connecting to Oracle 9i, I got ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested when querying.

- oracle 9i
- apache drill version 1.19 and 1.3 (both tested)
- ojdbc8_g-21.3.0.0.jar

"show schemas" works well

Please help me

Comment: Oracle 9i is _ancient_! Like 20+ years old. There's a good chance that a modern JDBC driver just isn't backwards compatible.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. The community will help you with your issues, but cannot do so when given nothing bet an error message. Please spend a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to review [ask]. At an absolute minimum you need to post the code generating the error.